# Get bone rotation from IK

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

Is it possible to get the xyz euler rotation of the bones in an armature that is controlled by the iTaSC IK solver with python?

With the rotation I mean the difference e.g. between the start and end of the IK movement i.e. boneA - y rotation 80 °.

Comment: Select a bone in pose mode and see if `[degrees(a) for a in C.active_pose_bone.matrix_channel.to_euler()]` , typed into the python console (where `C = bpy.context`), gives you the result you are after.